# Finding the PDF of a function of a normal and uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is my question:

Let $\alpha$ follow a uniform distribution on $[0, 2\pi]$, and $r$ follow a normal distribution $N(R,\sigma^2)$.
We define $x=r \ cos(\alpha)$ and and $y = r \ sin(\alpha)$.
What would be the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$?

Here are a summary of my thoughts. $r$ and $\alpha$ are independant, thus the joint PDF is simply the product of the two separate PDF: $f_{R,A}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma ^2}} exp(-\frac{(r-R)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}) \frac{1}{2 \pi}$

Then, I know I can do a change of variable from $(r, \alpha)$ to $(x,y)$, and if I compute the corresponding jacobian I should obtain the new joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ in which I am interested. However, the problem is that the change of variable is not unique. For instance, if I take the square of the definition of $x$ and $y$, I obtain the expression of $r$ as a function of the new random variable: $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. The problem is, when I take the square root of the equation, which I must do in order to compute the jacobian, I have two solution (positive and negative root). Any idea on how I should proceed ?

What I did in order to try something, is trying with the positive square root. Then, I can obtain $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\alpha = arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$.
Computing the jacobian, I obtain $J=\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$, which leads to:

$\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) &= f_{R,A}(r(x,y),\alpha(x,y)) \ |J| \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma ^2}} exp(-\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}) \frac{1}{2 \pi}\frac{2|xy|}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align} $

In order to account for the case of the negative square root, should I just add the same expression but with the negative square root ? (i.e. with $(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+R)^2$ in the exponential)

I know a similar thread exists here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113988/deriving-a-pdf-for-an-annulus-distribution/113991#113991, but it's more a numerical approach.

Thanks in advance !